# Correct format for web.config

Tags: asp.net, asp-classic, web-config

I'm having a correct format of my web.config file now i'm trying to add session timeout line in the script to increase the session time but its not working.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
  <system.webServer>

    <httpErrors errorMode="Detailed" />

<httpProtocol>
<customHeaders>

<add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*" />
</customHeaders>
</httpProtocol> 

<sessionState timeout="20" />




  </system.webServer>


</configuration>
```

Answer (score 1):

as you have tagged asp-classic in your question, can you confirm if you are extending the timeout of .asp or .aspx files?

As I understand it, web.config only affects .aspx files, you will need to modify the session timeout in a global.asa file in the root of your site to affect .asp files.

```
<SCRIPT LANGUAGE="VBScript" RUNAT="Server">
Sub Session_OnStart
    Session.Timeout = 20
End Sub
</SCRIPT>
```

This can also be defined in the web site property pages in IIS.

As memory serves, the default is 20 anyway, so changing it to 20 won't make much difference unless it's set to something else, somewhere else.

Comment: can i increase the value to about 20,000?

Comment: Try it and see what happens. I don't see why not. This will increase the load on the web server as it needs to keep more concurrent sessions alive. It sounds like you are trying to achieve a session-less website, perhaps this might be better achieved via cookies and the request.cookies and response.cookies objects.

Comment: 20,000 is a bad idea.  If you want to keep someone logged in for more than a reasonable about of time, then just create a iframe page called extend session and have it refresh via meta tag every 15 or so minutes.  This will refresh the session cookie so long as the browser is open and the iframe keeps refreshing.   This is how banks do it, except they bug you via javascript every 14 minutes and ask you before they refresh the iframe.